# All system quick menus (wifi, calendar, etc) get stuck open, how can I fix this?

Tags: windows-10

I've been having this Windows 10 issue for weeks now where these menus:

[task bar menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOXt1.png)

keep getting stuck open. The only way I've figured out to close them is to restart my PC, which is obviously a huge pain. I've let Windows update when it restarts, the issue didn't go away. The menus stay focused above all other UI, so I can't see that corner of my screen once the issue happens. I haven't figured out a pattern for re-creating it, and it doesn't always happen, it seems random. Also once it happens, I can no longer right click on the task bar or windows icon or any item within the Windows menu once you click on the Windows icon, for example to open task manager.

I've googled the issue and searched around but I can't find any support threads that reference the problem, so it must be something unique or rare.

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this, or at least how to kill that UI manually if there's no known fix?

Comment: You wrote "once it happens, I can no longer right click on the task bar or windows icon or any item within the Windows menu"  <-- The time I saw this (close enough), I had to do a Windows 10 Repair Install to fix it.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Run.
This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Comment: If you restart Explorer.exe in Task Manager that will fix it.